# Changing the Dataframe to a TimeSeries Array [Python]

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to change a date frame with the following contents:

|  | Date | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1802 | 2017-09-14 | -1.14% |
| 462 | 2021-05-16 | NaN |
| 935 | 2020-01-29 | 0.04% |
| 713 | 2020-09-07 | 2.39% |
| 1471 | 2018-08-11 | NaN |

[1460 rows × 2 columns]

Into this:

TimeSeries (DataArray) (Month: 144component: 1sample: 1)

array([[[112.]],

```
   [[118.]],

   [[132.]],

   [[129.]],

   [[121.]],

   [[135.]],

   [[148.]],

   [[148.]],

   [[136.]],
```

Coordinates:

| Month | (Month) | datetime64[ns]. | 2019-01-01 ... 2021-12-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **component** | (component) | object | 'Change' |

Attributes:

| static_covariates: None |
| --- |
| hierarchy: None |

In order to run a neural network model on multiple time series.
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution required removing the '%' sign from the column values. Then converting the column to a float.

`ftse_change['Change'] = ftse_change['Change'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0`

- did the trick